# How can I change down arrow color in a filter header of a list

Tags: css, filter

[image]

Hello,

Above is the image of the header of a list that is filterable. List is a webpart in a sharepoint page.

However the color scheme makes the down arrow barely visible. I cannot change the all look as I have to keep this color scheme for the site.

Hence my question, is it possible to either change the down arrow color or image ?

Thanks in advance the experts.

Comment: Inspect the arrow element to get its class. Then add this `color:#fff` in a common css file or inside CEWP..

Comment: I have found the element which is a picture. I've tried to replace the picture by replacing it in the catalog however catalog updates with the default picture at every log in. Don't know how to replace it using my own picture using CSS.

Comment: Place your image in common library then refer it from there..`background-image:url('.../file.jpg') !important;width:2px;height:2px;` keyword `!important` would force browser to user your css...